# Length getting wrong value

Tags: javascript, jquery, console, console.log

So, I have this code:

```
function getSubs(){
$element = document.getElementsByClassName("comclass");
console.log($element);
$parents = document.getElementsByClassName("parclass");
console.log($parents);
$length = $parents.length;
console.log($length);
}
```

For some unknown reason, console log from $parents shows the number of elements, seeing it's length using chrome console shows the real length, but the console log from $length doesn't count the children elements that have the class "parclass" even thought $parents shows them.. Any ideas to how to solve it?

EDIT:
Here's some of the HTML:

```
<div id="comment" class="comclass">
<div id="parent" class="parclass">
    <h4>Texto:</h4>asd<br>
    <h4>User:</h4>alan<h6 onclick="inputSub(this)">Com</h6>
    <p id="id">24</p>
</div>
<div id="input"></div>
<div id="childs">
    <div id="comment" class="comclass">
        <div id="parent" class="parclass">
            <h4>Texto:</h4>dd<br>
            <h4>User:</h4>alan<h6 onclick="inputSub(this)">Com</h6>
            <p id="id">25</p>
        </div>
        <div id="input"></div>
        <div id="childs"></div>
    </div> 
</div>
</div>
<div id="comment" class="comclass">
<div id="parent" class="parclass">
    <h4>Texto:</h4>a<br>
    <h4>User:</h4>alan<h6 onclick="inputSub(this)">Com</h6>
    <p id="id">31</p>
</div>
<div id="input"></div>
<div id="childs"></div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the ".comment" inside childs is generated afterwards with PHP and Ajax, and the selectors can't find it.

Comment: Please share the related HTML as well.

Comment: Does `getSubs` get called on `$(document).ready`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you tagged the question with the `jQuery`, I'll try to give you one jQuery implementation for that (and this might help you):

```
function getSubs(){
  var element = $(".comclass");
  console.log(element);

  var parents = $(".parclass");
  console.log(parents);

  var length = $(parents).length;
  console.log(length);
}
```

the queries performed should return a list with all elements that have a class named .comclass (first statement) and .parclass (second statement)

If this does not help you in any way, please edit the question posting some of the HTML for us to reproduce the error.

Comment: Different from the command "getElementsByClassName", your's only returns 2 element and 2 parents, even thought there's another one. I just remembered that the third one is generated after the function is called and that might be the problem. But how come "getElementsByClassName" can find the third element and $(".parclass") can't?

Comment: @alaneugenio, you should really update your question with the whole code to replicate your problem.

Comment: The problem here is that most of my code is generated with PHP and Ajax, the "real" HTML is almost empty

Comment: alan eugenio, can't you get it from the browser (when the HTML is already served and complete)?

Comment: If you're using AJAX or any assync calls to put the HTML together, than you can't exactly know what will already be in the DOM when that function runs... In that case, you would have to call it from a completion point on your assembly of the whole page.